# Show Application only in a VNC server Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, vnc-server

I have an application I have written for a customer, they want to be able to show the application via a vnc connection instead of a monitor, the reason for this is, the monitor connection will be used to display some digital signage.

so what I am looking for ( I think ) is something similar to what you can do in Linux, which creates a virtual desktop, and displays that via the VNC connection, and just runs it in memory.

This is all done on a Windows 10 system, and is on a small format board, similar to a Pi.

I have searched all over, I found one program, but it just didn't seem to work, I had to run it in XP compatibility mode !!

any advice would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can install an *X-server* on *Windows Subsystem for Linux*.

This one is the first I found with *google*: https://x410.dev

PS there are also other *X-server* for *Windows*, you just need to search for them.

Comment: thanks for the swift response, i am actually running windows 10, and want to run my .net wpf application through the VNC server on windows.  I just referred to Linux, as this is the functionality I need on windows.

Comment: This is for Windows 10. Only other way would be to use some kind of virtual monitor in Windows 10 and move one program on the real monitor and your _user program_ on the virtual monitor, while using VNC to show the virtual monitor. Windows 10 itself has nothing like an X-Server.

Comment: yeah, I looked at that, but from what i can see, there isnt a way of creating a virtual monitor in windows 10 anymore. ?